# Nested Map. Iteration over a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to add an element to a nested list. An example of the nested list is given below:

```
cordxy = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{7, 8}, {9, 10}, {1, 2}}}
```

I would like to add an element to the elements of the list without changing the structure of the list. Basically, the result I want is (assuming the extra element is a):

```
{{{1, 2, a}, {3, 4, a}, {5, 6, a}}, {{7, 8, a}, {9, 10, a}, {1, 2, a}}}
```

I have found a way of doing so by mapping a `Map` function (or `Nest`-ing a `Map`):

```
Map[Map[Insert[#, a, {3}] &, #] &, cordxy]
```

I would like to know if there is better way of doing it.

Thanks in advance, Drod

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative to `Map`:

```
Replace[cordxy, {x_, y_} :> {x, y, a}, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, a}, {3, 4, a}, {5, 6, a}},
>  {{7, 8, a}, {9, 10, a}, {1, 2, a}}}
> ```

Or alternatively one can use `ReplaceAll` with an appropriate pattern; this would avoid the need to specify an explicit replacement level:

```
cordxy /. {x_?NumberQ, y_} :> {x, y, a}
```

Comment: I was also looking for a rule based method. Although I think this is not as effecient as Map. I will investigate it.

Comment: @Drod glad it helps, and thank you for the accept! Since you are interested in replacement based solutions, I added another approach using a replacement with a restricted pattern.

Answer (score 11):

```
Map[Append[a], cordxy, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, a}, {3, 4, a}, {5, 6, a}}, 
>  {{7, 8, a}, {9, 10, a}, {1, 2,  a}}}
> ```

and

```
Map[Map @ Append @ a] @ cordxy
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, a}, {3, 4, a}, {5, 6, a}}, 
>  {{7, 8, a}, {9, 10, a}, {1, 2, a}}}
> ```

Comment: Why are these thing so simple when you see then?! Thanks kglr

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternative way.

```
PadRight[#, Dimensions@# + {0, 1}, a] & /@ cordxy
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, a}, {3, 4, a}, {5, 6, a}}, {{7, 8, a}, {9, 10, a}, {1, 2, a}}}
> ```

Comment: No need to map - just use PadRight directly...

Comment: @ciao Sorry, I don't get it. Can you please be more clear..

Comment: I think `PadRight[{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{7, 8}, {9, 10}, {1, 2}}}, {Automatic, Automatic, 3}, a]` is what @ciao had in mind.

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci: For example, `PadRight[#, 
  Dimensions[#] // # + UnitVector[Length@#, Length@#] &, #2] &` will pad lowest level, regardless of depth. (Called with original array and desired pad element).

Comment: @ciao `PadRight[#, Dimensions[#] // # + UnitVector[Length@#, Length@#] &, 
   a] &@cordxy` works for the list above but if we have `cordxy = {{{1, 2, 2}, {3, 4, 2}, {5, 6, 2}}, {{7, 8}, {9, 10}, {1,  2}}};` will not work?

Comment: @J.M. your solution only works if sublists have 2 columns.

Comment: @Okkes, indeed, so you change the last entry in `{Automatic, Automatic, 3}` to an appropriate number for other cases. The point is the use of `Automatic`.

Answer (score 7):

Or you can use `ReplaceRepeated`

```
{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{7, 8}, {9, 10}, {1, 2}}} //. {x_?NumericQ, y_} :> {x, y, a}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{7, 8}, {9, 10}, {1, 2}}};
```

Using `ReplaceAll`

```
list /. x : {__?AtomQ} :> Append[x, a]
```

{{{1, 2, a}, {3, 4, a}, {5, 6, a}}, {{7, 8, a}, {9, 10, a}, {1, 2,
a}}}

Using `Cases`

```
Cases[list, x : {__} :> Append[a] /@ x]
```

{{{1, 2, a}, {3, 4, a}, {5, 6, a}}, {{7, 8, a}, {9, 10, a}, {1, 2,
a}}}

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{7, 8}, {9, 10}, {1, 2}}};
```

Using `Thread`:

```
Append @@@ Thread[{#, a}] & /@ list

(*{{{1, 2, a}, {3, 4, a}, {5, 6, a}}, {{7, 8, a}, {9, 10, a}, {1, 2, a}}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cordxy = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{7, 8}, {9, 10}, {1, 2}}};

cordxy /. x_?VectorQ :> Join[x, {a}]
```

> {{{1, 2, a}, {3, 4, a}, {5, 6, a}}, {{7, 8, a}, {9, 10, a}, {1, 2,
> a}}}

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrayFlatten[{{#, a}}] & /@ cordxy

(* {{1, 2, a}, {3, 4, a}, {5, 6, a}}, {{7, 8, a}, {9, 10, a}, {1, 2, a}} *)
```